# call_user_func returns false when it shouldn't

Tags: php

I've tried to make a controller for all my forms, so that i can easily call them via AJAX, and not worry about creating new functions for each request. But for some reason, returns false when i asks if the function exists - when it does.

```
if(function_exists('_'.$method)) call_user_func('_'.$method);
else die(json_encode(array("alert('wrong request " . $method . "')"), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));

function _subscribe_moeder(){
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)) 
         die(json_encode(array("$('#email').addClass('has-error')", 'alert("error")'),  JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
     else 
         die(json_encode(array("$('#email').removeClass('has-error')", 'alert("success")'), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
} // End function _subscribe_moeder
```

the $method comes from the form which the user submitted.

What i've tried so far:

1. `trim $method`
2. put the function name directly into the "function_exists" checkpoint (`function_exists('_subscribe_moeder')`)

Comment: consider using classes and magic methods?

Comment: I agree with @RoyalBg, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: yeah, crossed my mind, and then flew away. I think i'll make it into a class.

Comment: I'm also confused as to why you're converting an array to an object for client use. If, for example, you had `["alert('hi');"]` you'll end up with `{"0":"alert('hi');"}`.

Comment: And you most probably get wrong data in $method. Have you var_dumped it when the form is submitted to see what does it contain? Because this code works for me `$method = 'subscribe_moeder';
if(function_exists('_'.$method)) call_user_func('_'.$method);
else die(json_encode(array("alert('wrong request " . $method . "')"), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));

function _subscribe_moeder(){
  var_dump('asd');
}`

Comment: Please clarify: are you using plain procedural functions, rather than OOP class methods?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario in this script i only use procedural functions yes. I do however initiate a PDO class up the top of the script. Don't know if that will help.


@RoyalBg as i stated in OP, i've tried this `function_exists('_subscribe_moeder')` and that too returns false. i've tried to dump the `$method` and it returns the correct value.

Comment: shouldn't you be placing `if(function_exists('_'.$method))...` after function definition??

Comment: Well, I'm afraid I [cannot reproduce the issue](https://eval.in/172865). But you could use some basic debuggin, at least var_dump()'ing `$method`.

Comment: @code-jaff You got it right! thank you so much, i don't know why the heck i didn't think of that!

Comment: @code-jaff - Please see [my fiddle](https://eval.in/172865), that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario yes, I was wondering that it's prove me wrong. Now I confused totally :(, does php version matter?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario but... but.... but, why doesn't reality work anymnore? how come your fiddle works, when mine doesn't?

Comment: I've hard-coded `$method` in my fiddle. You're reading it from... from somewhere. Have you var_dump()'ed it yet?

Comment: Yes, I also posted an example 7 posts ago, where it works with hardcoded $method..

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario `var_dump($method)` return: `string(16) "subscribe_moeder"`. so that should work, no?